# Cannot fix array formula sum with if statement

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have an `ARRAYFORMULA` that adds up a whole column of data based on a condition, but I need to adjust the formula separately so it adds up the data based on two conditions. It works with only one condition but when I try to adjust it stops working.

This is the formula that works:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(All!$AI3:$AI <> "GB", All!$J3:$J, "0")))
```

It adds up the value of all items in a column that do not contain "GB". AI is the column that contains the country code (including GB) and column J contains the value of that item.

I want it to add up all the items that do not contain GB, from a certain date range.

I tried to adjust the formula like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(OR(REGEXMATCH(All!$C$3:$C$11000, A6), All!$AI3:$AI <> "GB"), All!$J3:$J, "0")))
```

So it checks if column C contains the date held in A6, and if column AI contains "GB", then theoretically should add up the result. When I use `OR` it adds up every single value in column J. When I use `AND` instead of `OR` the result is 0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit for clarification:**

I am using `REGEXMATCH` because I only need to check if column C contains what is in A6 - the dates in C have year, month, day and time, I only need to check if it contains the year and month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED (base on comment of OP)

See if this works..

```
=sumproduct(text(B:B; "mm/yyyy")=text(A1; "mm/yyyy");D:D<>"GB";E:E  )
```

or

```
=sumproduct(year(B:B)=year(A1); month(B:B)=month(A1);D:D<>"GB";E:E  )
```

Comment: I was using `REGEXMATCH` because I needed to check if C contains part of the date - the full date contains the year, month, day and time, whereas I only need to match the year and month. Apologies for not clarifying this in the question.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works great and everything is running smoothly. I really appreciate you taking your time to help me out.